# Unit Testing Exception OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have a web application Spring + Hibernate based and it run/works well. But when I try to test it via unit test, I got the:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z"

I read a lot of about this problem, all people say it come due to JPA1 and place JPA2 on your classpath. But I don't have any JPA1 based jar on my classpath yet Hibernate's own provided JPA2 but still get the exception.

My Library stack is following,

Hibernate 3.6.8

- hibernate3.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
- hibernate-testing.jar
- antlr-2.7.6.jar
- commons-collections-3.1.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
- jta-1.1.jar
- slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

Spring Libraries 3.0.6

- org.springframework.aop;version="[3.0.6.RELEASE, 3.0.6.RELEASE]",
- org.springframework.asm;version="[3.0.6.RELEASE, 3.0.6.RELEASE]",
- org.springframework.aspects;version="[3.0.6.RELEASE, 3.0.6.RELEASE]",
- org.springframework.beans;version="[3.0.6.RELEASE, 3.0.6.RELEASE]",
- org.springframework.context;version="[3.0.6.RELEASE, 3.0.6.RELEASE]",
- org.springframework.context.support;version="[3.0.6.RELEASE, 3.0.6.RELEASE]",
- org.springframework.core;version="[3.0.6.RELEASE, 3.0.6.RELEASE]",
- org.springframework.expression;version="[3.0.6.RELEASE, 3.0.6.RELEASE]",
- org.springframework.jdbc;version="[3.0.6.RELEASE, 3.0.6.RELEASE]",
- org.springframework.jms;version="[3.0.6.RELEASE, 3.0.6.RELEASE]",
- org.springframework.orm;version="[3.0.6.RELEASE, 3.0.6.RELEASE]",
- org.springframework.oxm;version="[3.0.6.RELEASE, 3.0.6.RELEASE]",
- org.springframework.transaction;version="[3.0.6.RELEASE, 3.0.6.RELEASE]",
- org.springframework.web;version="[3.0.6.RELEASE, 3.0.6.RELEASE]",
- org.springframework.web.servlet;version="[3.0.6.RELEASE, 3.0.6.RELEASE]",
- org.springframework.web.portlet;version="[3.0.6.RELEASE, 3.0.6.RELEASE]",
- com.springsource.org.aopalliance;version="[1.0.0, 1.0.0]"

My Unit Test Code, very simple:

```
@ContextConfiguration( locations = {"classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml" } )
public class RegistrationServiceTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

   @Autowired
   RegisterationSerivce serivce;

   @Test
   public void getRegistrationRefData() {
      List list =  serivce.getAllCustomers( );
      System.out.println(list.size( ));
   }
}
```

I would be great thankful for any help in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the issue... it was due to "Java EE 5 Libraries" which contains following libraries.

```
-javaee.jar
-jsf-impl.jar
-jsf-api.jar
-jstl-1.2.jar
```

I am using MyEclipse Enterprise Workbench 9.0 which automatically adds "Java EE 5 Libraries" to every web project. So in case of JPA & JSF you want to use custom libraries, we must remove them.

Comment: As much as I can understand your frustration, would you mind to watch your language? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a JPA 1.0 jar somewhere in the classpath. Check output of the following statement to identify the exact location of that jar:

```
System.out.println(OneToMany.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
```

Comment: I will inspect this matter by your tip when on system. by the way where is best URL to download JPA 2.0? is it good to use hibernate's own provided one which is "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar" ? Thankx

Comment: javax.persistence.OneToMany.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource() It gives me null.